# How to change the size of the inputs with a bias in a custom layer in Tensorflow Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a custom layer like in this example:

```
class SuperMaximum(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self,units, **kwargs):
        super(SuperMaximum, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.units = units
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(
            name="w",
            shape=(self.units,),
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
        )
        self.window = self.add_weight(
            name="window",
            shape=(self.units,),
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
        )
        
    def call(self, inputs):
      
        maximum = tf.math.reduce_max(inputs * self.w, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        
        return maximum
```

What i want to implement is a way to change the size of the inputs through the epochs (let's say the inputs size is 10 at for the first epoch the layer receive just 50% of the total inputs, and for the second 60%, etc.).
At first I though of adding those lines in the call function:

```
    def call(self, inputs):
        taille = len(inputs)
        taille = float(taille)
        inputsWindow = inputs[int(taille * (1.0-self.window)) : int(taille * (1.0+self.window))]
        maximum = tf.math.reduce_max(inputsWindow * self.w, axis=1, keepdims=True)
```

But without success. I have this following error:

```
TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got <tf.Tensor 'super_maximum_10/Cast_1:0' shape=(1,) dtype=int32>
```

The full stack trace:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [17], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 modelMeanCustom = ModelCustomSuperMean()
      2 modelMeanCustom.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])

Input In [16], in ModelCustomSuperMean()
      1 def ModelCustomSuperMean():
      2     inputs = keras.Input(shape=(500,), name="digits")
----> 3     x = SuperMean(1)(inputs)
      4     #x = tf.reshape(i, [1, x.shape[:&], 1])
      5     #y = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu',input_shape=(input_shape[1:]))(x)
      6     x1 = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu",name="firstCustomMean")(x)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filekzfux12n.py:12, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__call(self, inputs)
     10 taille = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(len), (ag__.ld(inputs),), None, fscope)
     11 taille = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(float), (ag__.ld(taille),), None, fscope)
---> 12 inputsWindow = ag__.ld(inputs)[ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(int), (ag__.ld(taille) * (1.0 - ag__.ld(self).window),), None, fscope):ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(int), (ag__.ld(taille) * (1.0 + ag__.ld(self).window),), None, fscope)]
     13 maximum = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).math.reduce_max, (ag__.ld(inputsWindow) * ag__.ld(self).w,), dict(axis=1, keepdims=True), fscope)
     14 try:

TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "super_mean_3" (type SuperMean).

in user code:

    File "4212493025.py", line 21, in call  *
        inputsWindow = inputs[int(taille * (1.0-self.window)) : int(taille * (1.0+self.window))]

    TypeError: Only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), tf.newaxis (`None`) and scalar tf.int32/tf.int64 tensors are valid indices, got <tf.Tensor 'super_mean_3/Cast_1:0' shape=(1,) dtype=int32>


Call arguments received by layer "super_mean_3" (type SuperMean):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 500), dtype=float32)
```

Next I tried this:

```
    def call(self, inputs):
        X = []
        for i in range(int(float(len(inputs)) * self.window)):
            X.append(test[i])
        
        X = tf.stack(X)
        X = tf.cast(X, tf.float32)        
        maximum = tf.math.reduce_max(X * self.w, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        
        return maximum
```

But obtain the following error:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1
         for 'limit' for '{{node super_maximum_13/range}} = Range[Tidx=DT_INT32](super_maximum_13/range/start, super_maximum_13/Maximum, super_maximum_13/range/delta)' with input shapes: [], [1], [].
```

With the full stack trace:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [55], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 modelSuperMaxCustom = ModelCustomSuperMax()
      2 modelSuperMaxCustom.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()])

Input In [54], in ModelCustomSuperMax()
      1 def ModelCustomSuperMax():
      2     inputs = keras.Input(shape=(500,), name="digits")
----> 3     x = SuperMaximum(1)(inputs)
      4     x1 = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu",name="firstCustomMax")(x)
      5     x2 = keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu",name="secondCustomMax")(x1)

File ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filecgyn4lib.py:22, in outer_factory.<locals>.inner_factory.<locals>.tf__call(self, inputs)
     20     ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(X).append, (ag__.ld(test)[ag__.ld(i)],), None, fscope)
     21 i = ag__.Undefined('i')
---> 22 ag__.for_stmt(ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(range), (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(int), (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(float), (ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(len), (ag__.ld(inputs),), None, fscope),), None, fscope) * ag__.ld(self).window,), None, fscope),), None, fscope), None, loop_body, get_state, set_state, (), {'iterate_names': 'i'})
     23 X = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).stack, (ag__.ld(X),), None, fscope)
     24 X = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(tf).cast, (ag__.ld(X), ag__.ld(tf).float32), None, fscope)

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "super_maximum_13" (type SuperMaximum).

in user code:

    File "816897845.py", line 21, in call  *
        for i in range(int(float(len(inputs)) * self.window)):

    ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1
         for 'limit' for '{{node super_maximum_13/range}} = Range[Tidx=DT_INT32](super_maximum_13/range/start, super_maximum_13/Maximum, super_maximum_13/range/delta)' with input shapes: [], [1], [].


Call arguments received by layer "super_maximum_13" (type SuperMaximum):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 500), dtype=float32)
```

Is there any other way where I can implement this ?
Thanks

Edit:
Here is the line that is throwing the error (for the both way tried):

```
def ModelCustomSuperMax():
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(500,), name="digits")
    x = SuperMaximum(1)(inputs)
    
    x1 = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation="relu",name="firstCustomMax")(x)
    x2 = keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu",name="secondCustomMax")(x1)
    outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1, name="predictionsCustomMax")(x2)

    return keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

modelSuperMaxCustom = ModelCustomSuperMax()
```

Comment: Can you post the lines that throw the error as well?

Comment: Sure, I edited the post to include the lines where the error is raised. For both ways I tried, the error is raised when I'm calling the function building the model.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace as well?

Comment: I should have edited to bring the full stack trace